# How can I use not exist or null in elasticsearch query (EQL) by using Nest C#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, nest, elk

Everyone know that Nest Elasticsearch is not easy and boring to make clarified queries for looking  something. I also stumpled upon this issue . As a result I could't use 'not empty' and null in my query.

```
   var list = client.Count<LogMessage>(s => s.Index("xxx-*").Query(q =>
            !q.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.Test.Suffix("keyword")).Value(null)) &&
            q.Term(t => t.Field(f => f.Environment.Suffix("keyword")).Value("yyy")) &&
            q.DateRange(t => t.Field(f => f.LogDate).GreaterThan(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15)))));
```

Null or string.Empty is not working here. How can I use NOT null or Not Empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO this isn't much of a NEST usability issue as it's just non-trivial to do this in Elasticsearch itself. I have had success by negating a wildcard query (`.Wilcard`) on that field and/or using `.Exists` to find documents which do not have that field because null values are not stored on a document and empty values are difficult to search for in non-keyword text fields because the analyzers will not look for blank values.

Please see this answer and the one below it which is even shorter. 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7515#issuecomment-158668403

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
 .Query(q => q.Bool(b => b
                       .Must(m => m
                            .Exists(e => e
                                .Field(f => f.Test)
                           )
                       )
                  ))
```

This checks for null values.